# iOS "Open in" menu not opening my app even though I updated my plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, uti

I want to open mail attachments of specific extension with the app I'm developing.
I was able to achieve adding the app to "Open In" menu:

[image]
<sub>(source: [macobserver.com](https://www.macobserver.com/imgs/landau/2011/File_sharing/Dropbox_Open_In.jpg))</sub>

But when I press on my app icon, nothing happens, not even the splash screen is shown.

In the PList I specified the document types and the Exported Type UTIs.
What can be the problem?

Comment: This happened sometimes to me on the Simulator, but always worked on the device.

Comment: In my case in happed on the device...